# WebKitBrowser with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to use the `WebKitBrowser` with a WPF application, but am getting a runtime error that says:

> FileNotFoundException was unhandled by user code:
>
> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in WpfApplication1.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'WebKit.Interop, Version=533.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b967213f6d29a3be' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The exception is occurring where I am creating an instance of the `WebKitBrowser` (inside the constructor of my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file):

```
System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();

WebKit.WebKitBrowser browser = new WebKit.WebKitBrowser();

browser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");

host.Child = browser;

browser.Show();

grdBrowserHost.Children.Add(host);
```

I have the required `using` statements at the top of my `.cs` file:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WebKit;
```

I have surrounded that code with a `try-catch` statement, but when I then run my code, the `WebKitBrowser` is not added to the window as I want it to be, so I'm guessing that the exception is being caught/ handled- though I don't see the `Console.WriteLine();` message that I added to my `try-catch` statement.

I have tried catching a `FileNotFoundException`, or an `Exception`, but with the same result- the application runs in exactly the same way as it did before I added the code to create an instance of the `WebKitBrowser`.

`grdBrowserHost` is the name that I gave to the `<grid></grid>` XML element where I want to display the browser, although I have not written anything inside that XML element- do I need something there to be able to display the browser? That part of my XML is:

```
<TabItem Header="Browser">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid x:Name="grdBrowserHost">
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</TabItem>
```

**Edit**

Although I will want to be using the `WebKit` browser, or another browser that supports JavaScript, etc, I've had a look into using the 'built in' web browser provided by WPF, and have edited my XAML to include the following markup inside the `<StackPanel></StackPanel>` tags where I want to display the browser:

```
<WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Height="100"
                            Margin="10, 10, 0, 0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            Width="100"
                            Name="BuiltInBrowser" />
```

In the Design view in Visual Studio 2015, this markup shows a rectangular area on my application window where the browser will be displayed, however, when I run the application, the `WebBrowser` is not displayed on the main window, even though the Design view in Visual Studio 2015 is showing a rectangular area (grey colouring) where the `WebBrowser` is located.

Why isn't the `WebBrowser` being displayed on the application window when I run the application, even though it is being displayed in the Design view?

How can I display a `WebKitBrowser` here, rather than a `WebBrowser`?

If I try to open `<WebKitBrowser></WebKitBrowser>` tags in my XAML, that line displays a compile error message that says:

> WebKitBrowser is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project

How can I include/ reference `WebKitBrowser` so that it is supported, and I can use it?

Comment: Is the WebKit.Interop file in the same directory as your built executable?

Comment: I couldn't find a WebKit.Interop file... no idea what that is? But I'm guessing not, as I have imported `WebKit` into my C# with a `using` statement... i.e. `using WebKit;`

Comment: Ok, so there was a `WebKit.Interop.dll` file in my `bin/Release` folder- I've copied that into the `bin/Debug` folder, but although the line `WebKitBrowser browser = new WebKitBrowser();` is being called from inside the `private void Window_Loaded_1(...)` function, I can't actually see the browser displayed in my GUI...

Answer (score 0):

The using statement only saves you typing the namespace repeatedly within that source file; You'll have added a project reference to the Webkit.Interop (or to a COM class library which will generate an Interop file for you). That dll is required at runtime, hence your error.

Comment: I haven't done that specifically... I tried doing it just now (Project --> Add Reference), but couldn't find `WebKit.Interop` in any of the options there, and it said that "no items were found" when I searched for it....

Comment: If you're getting that error, you've already added the reference, but may have deleted the Interop file. Either recreate the reference like you did last time, or undelete the file.

Comment: I have never seen/ come across the `Interop` file.. I definitely haven't deleted it- I haven't deleted anything... so can't undelete it...